# How do I import a three.js (JSON) model into Unity at runtime?

Tags: unity-game-engine, three.js

I have a Unity app which I would like to import a 3D model from a location on the Internet. I know how to download the resource, but how can you instantiate the JS model into a Unity mesh / object.

Comment: what language are you using in your project?

Comment: @Dunno  I am using C#.

Comment: did you do any progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First you need to parse the JSON and get the geometry, uv and normals. (info about the format is at https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/JSON-Geometry-format-4)
2. Then you can use the Mesh class to dynamically instantiate a mesh into a game object (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GeneratingMeshGeometryProcedurally.html)